# Copy files from specific directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shell

I want to copy files witch part of they folder name is same e.g ../example/test_n, n is from 1 to 15. I saw a resolution when using bash, we just need to write one line and it would be cp ../example/test* ..example/dest. And my question is, is there a equal operation in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent of your bash sample with a wildcard could be

```
Copy-Item C:\example\test* C:\example\dest\ -recurse
```

Assuming you don't need to have a control to limit the 1-15 range.